# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'workerThread' (PHP Pthreads)

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and Xampp. I'm having trouble using pthreads.

The error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'workerThread' not found
```

My code is

```
class workerThread extends Thread {
public function __construct($i){
  $this->i=$i;
}

public function run(){
  while(true){
   echo $this->i;
   sleep(1);
  }
}
}


function run() {
    global $profilesCount, $profilesNames;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $profilesCount+2; $i++) {
$workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
$workers[$i]->start();
        }
}
```

- The PHP version is `7.0.6`
- The pthreads version is `3.1.6`
- PHP Extension Build is `API20151012,TS,VC14`
- I tried both the 32bit and 64bit pthreads versions
- I copied `php_pthreads.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext\`
- I copied `pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\`, `C:\xampp\apache\bin`, `C:\windows\system32`
- Apache wasn't starting with `extension=php_pthreads.dll` added to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`, so I copied the file to `C:\xampp\php\php-cli.ini` with `extension=php_pthreads.dll`

Any ideas? I appreciate your help.